# Get number of checked checkboxes( having same class) -Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC page i am generating a group of check boxes. Every check box have sameclass called 'resultTableCheckBox'

I want to get number of selected checkboxes .I tried following code

```
  $(".resultTableCheckBox").live('click', function (event) {
           alert($(".resultTableCheckBox :checked").length);
         });
```

But above code always alert 0. I tried

```
  $(".resultTableCheckBox").live('click', function (event) {
           alert($(".resultTableCheckBox ").length);
         });
```

Now its alert the total number of checkboxes having same class resultTableCheckBox. But how can i get number of selected check boxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is finding all children of all `.resultTableCheckBox` elements that are checked.  You need to add the ":checked" selector directly to the class.

```
$(".resultTableCheckBox:checked")
```

Answer (score 3):

Lose the space:

```
$(".resultTableCheckBox:checked").length
```

Answer (score 1):

The :checked selected should not have a space.  Tested it and it works.

```
$(".resultTableCheckBox:checked")
```